# cant access to array after json decode

Tags: php, json

i send data in ajax and get it in the php, i encode the data and then i do decode, the problem is that the insert sql query is not working probebly because the syntax that i use is not right..

here is the php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
//$action_name = $_POST['action_name'];
$data = json_decode(json_decode($_POST['data']));
$data0 = echo $data[0];
$data1 = echo $data[1];
$data2 = echo $data[2];
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Expenses (accountid, category, date, amount, repeated) VALUES ('$accountid', '$data0', '$data1', '$data2', '0')");
//$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Expenses (accountid, category, date, amount, repeated) VALUES ('$accountid', 'test1', 'test1', 'test1', '0')");}
```

i tryed to use print insted of echo, the resualt was the insert was work but the data was wrong, it add the number 1 to all the fileds in the sql...

the data before i send with the ajax look like this: ["E2","08/22/2015","33","1","cc"]

please help! =]

Comment: why do you use json_decode twice?
Use `var_dump($data)` to see what the result of the function is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming json is successfully posted, your server side php script should look something like the posted code. **Most importantly** I'm using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

```
$_POST['data'] = '["E2","08/22/2015","33","1","cc"]';

if(isset($_POST['data'])){

    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    // print_r($data);
    error_log(print_r($data,1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);

    $accountid = 1;
    $category = $data[0];
    $date = $data[1];
    $amount = $data[2];
    $repeated = 0;

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASENAME','USERNAME','PASSWORD');

    $sql = '
        INSERT INTO Expenses (
            accountid,
            category,
            date,
            amount,
            repeated
        ) 
        VALUES (
            :accountid,
            :category,
            :date,
            :amount,
            :repeated       
        )';

    try {
        $r = $db->prepare($sql);
        $r->bindParam(':accountid', $accountid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $r->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $r->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $r->bindParam(':amount', $amount, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $r->bindParam(':repeated', $repeated, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $r->execute();
        $n = $r->rowCount();
        if ($n) {
            $id = $db->lastInsertId();
            // print_r($id);
            error_log(print_r($id,1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        error_log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is in my insert, i just see it right now...quoats problem...
can somone look on the inser pealse?


TY all! you best!

Comment: "INSERT INTO Expenses (accountid, category, date, amount, repeated) VALUES ('".$accountid."', '".$data0."', '".$data1."', '".$data2."', '0'
)");

Answer (score 0):

convert your javascript array to string before send to php.

```
 var data = ["E2","08/22/2015","33","1","cc"];
    dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { data: dataString},
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

and php page

```
      <?php
        $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

        print_r($data);

        $data0 = $data[0];
        $data1 = $data[1];
        $data2 = $data[2];


        ?>
```

Try this